# Redirect Sharepoint Custom List Images a URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, hyperlink, slider

I made a webpart that slides each image in custom list. I want to redirect each image a url. How can i do that with a "hyperlink column" in list or through the source code?

My code is like this:

```
                        List<Slider> _lstSlider = new List<Slider>();

                        if (spLstItemsSlider != null)
                        {
                            foreach (SPListItem item in spLstItemsSlider)
                            {
                                Slider slide = new Slider();

                                //slide.Title = Convert.ToString(item["Title"]);
                                //slide.Description = Convert.ToString(item["Description"]);

                                foreach (string fileName in item.Attachments)
                                {
                                    SPFile file = _spWeb.GetFile(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
                                    slide.ImgUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl;
                                }

                                _lstSlider.Add(slide);
                            }

                            rptSlider.DataSource = _lstSlider;
                            rptSlider.DataBind();
                        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the sole purpose of this list is to host the images to be displayed in a slideshow then I would use the built-in Picture Library with a Hyperlink column instead. This way you get to take advantage of the built-in Picture Library Slideshow Web Part as well, which might eliminate the need for creating a custom slideshow web part.

If the built-in web part does not satisfy your needs and/or you have to use a custom list then you can access to the attachments of a list item via [ListUrl]/Attachments/[ListItemId]/[AttachmentFileName] url format. For example, if you have a list item with id 1 and an attachment called image1.jpg stored under a list called Slideshow, the URL of the attachment would be "/Slideshow/Attachments/1/image1.jpg". After getting the right URL to the image all you need to do is to get the URL that image is supposed to point to which could be stored on the same list in a text or hyperlink column.

I hope this helps...